# javascript regex for score

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

What is the Regex for students marks like this: 12.5, 99.5, 87 , 1.66

- the field can be empty
- max characters length with (.) is  5 like this: 99.99
- the marks are between 0 and 100

I used this, but it doesn't work

```
var rmark = /^\d{0,1}\.|(\d{0,4})$/;


        var txtS = $(":text");

        for (var i = 0; i < txtS.length; i++) {
            if (!rmark.test(txtS.eq(i).val())) {
                er = 1; break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: what effort have you made?

Comment: var rmark = /^\d{0,1}\.|(\d{0,4})$/;

Comment: Are the commas part of it, or are you splitting on the commas first?  Because if they are part of it, then the `^` and `$` won't be helpful here.

Comment: Ok, this is what you want `/^\d{1,2}(\.\d{1,2})?$/` - test it here http://regex101.com/r/cX1qL4/1

Comment: @Takpar your regexp is wrong. What is wrong with the one I wrote?

Comment: I test your regex in http://regex101.com but and it works, but it doesn't work in my code!

Comment: @Takpar Than you are doing something wrong. Can not tell what is wrong without seeing your final code.

Comment: in your regex, 100 isn't in range

Comment: @Takpar because I'm updating my answer, not my comments. Do you see it with all variations of regexps??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://regex101.com/r/cX1qL4/1

```
/^\d{1,2}(\.\d{1,2})?$/
```

And it means...

```
^           - from the start of the string
  \d{1,2}   - 1 or 2 digits
  (         - capture group that is not required
    \.      - escaped dot
    \d{1,2} - 1 or 2 digits
  )?        - this group is not required to present in the string
$           - end of the string
```

ps: if it can be empty then `/^(\d{1,2}(\.\d{1,2})?)?$/`

pps: if range from 0 to 100 then `/^(100|(\d{1,2})(\.\d{1,2})?)?$/`

or you can test it here - **run the snippet**

```js
$(function(){
 $('input').keyup(function() {
  var regexp = /^(100|(\d{1,2})(\.\d{1,2})?)?$/;
  if (!regexp.test($(this).val()))
    $(this).addClass('bad');
  else
    $(this).removeClass('bad');
 });
});
```

```css
.bad {color:red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text">
```

Comment: Excuse me the range is between 0 and 100

Answer (score 2):

Since it seems the strings you want to validate come from `<input type="text">` elements, you could use HTML5 validation instead of JS one, and just let the browser do it for you:

```html
<input type="number" max="99.99" min="0" step=".01" />
```

But even if you need to validate using JS, you can still use HTML5 validation instead of regex:

```js
var isValid = (function() {
    var el = document.createElement('input');
    el.type = "number";
    el.max = 99.99;
    el.min = 0;
    el.step = .01;
    return function isValid(value) {
        el.value = value;
        return el.validity.valid;
    };
})();
```